# tomcat in Eclipse: Deploy more than one project

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, tomcat

I am deploying a dynamic web project in Eclipse. But this project needs to talk with another project which does not get deployed, that project is always deployed if i start tomcat outside eclipse but then again i don't know how to deploy my dynamic web project outside Eclipse.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this step if you want to deploy a dynamic web project outside eclipse:

1. Right click on your project, choose `Export`.
2. Choose `WAR file`.
3. Set the destination: `<apache directory>\webapps`.
4. Restart tomcat.